# Is there a way to print a regexp match with AWK?

Tags: awk, gawk

I want to check that particular string "20040213_25049.XXXX" containing XXXX or not on other hand when do I write string like "20040213_25049 .XXXX" then it is matched but I want to match with "20040213_25049.XXXX"

```
echo "20040213_25049 .XXXX" | awk '{match($2,/XXXX/,a)}END{print a[0]}' (It is working)
echo "20040213_25049.XXXX" | awk '{match($2,/XXXX/,a)}END{print a[0]}' (It is not working)
```

I didn't get any output from above line.

Comment: You are matching the second field. There is no second field.... I am guessing that you have just copied this code and have absolutely no idea how it works at all. Look [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

Comment: JID@thnx for ur reply basically I'm trying to match sub-string XXXX with "20040213_25049.XXXX" but not able to match on other hand when do I write  like this "20040213_25049 .XXXX" then I'm able to match.

Comment: What is it you are looking for to get as an output/result?  `yes/no`, the `XXXX` itself?  or does `XXXX` represent a number you like to get?

Comment: I know what you are trying to do. If you look at the link i posted and actually have a basic understanding of how awk works then you would be able to do it.

Comment: @Jotne They have clearly put in no effort at all and don't even understand the concept of fields in awk.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some like this:

```
echo "20040213_25049.XXXX" | awk '/[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{5}\.XXXX/ {print "yes"}'
yes
```

It will test if you have  `5` digits followed by a `.` and 4 `X`

Or like this?

```
echo "20040213_25049.XXXX" | awk '/20040213_25049\.XXXX/ {print "yes"}'
yes

echo "20040213_25049. XXXX" | awk '/20040213_25049\.XXXX/ {print "yes"}'
```

Comment: Not even remotely what OP asked for.Mybe you should wait for them to answer your question instead of rushing to answer for imaginary points.

Comment: @JID it does this `I want to check that particular string "20040213_25049.XXXX" containing XXXX or not`

Comment: It doesn't `Is there a way to print a regexp match with AWK?`